# Angular throws an error while trying to navigate the app

Tags: angular, error-handling

So i'm building an app with angular and laravel.
Everything was working just fine - I was logged in and minding my own business.
Then, I logged out, and when I wanted to log back in my app just didn't cooperate anymore..
Im using laravel with JWT in the backend.
Im trying to go to different routes in the app like Login or Signup and I get the error:

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[false -> false -> false]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for false!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[false -> false -> false]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for false!
```

****My App module:****

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/signup/signup.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { ResultsComponent } from './components/dashboard/results/results.component';
import { PricingComponent } from './components/pricing/pricing.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ResultsComponent,
    PricingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: ADDING HTTP SERVICE:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api';
  login(form) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`, form);
  }
  signup(form) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/signup`, form);
  }
  findVehicle(vehicleNumber = 'empty') {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/findVehicle/${vehicleNumber}`);
  }
  getPricing(year) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/get-pricing/${year}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information here, but I suspect the issue might be in HttpService..

Comment: Yes definitely, please add more information

Comment: I've added. Feel free to check it out

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER FOUND
so it turns out that you can't use a ! as a provider.
I have used

```
    canActivate: [!AfterLoginService],
```

and this was the problem.